# I dont understand why this code has an error

Tags: java

Im working on a code for homework to make a String upper case but without using toUpperCase specifically. So im using toUpperCase(char) then using a for loop to go through the String one by one. For some reason it error's. By the way str is defined by my teacher but it is random.

```
int len = str.length();

for(int i = 0;i < len;i++)

{

    char cur = str.charAt(i);

    char cur = Character.toUpperCase(char);

}
```

i dont see the error

Comment: Please include the actual error message. That will tell us (and you) what the problem is.

Comment: I am voting to close as I believe this kind of question ("why isn't my code working") is off-topic on stackoverflow. If there is a specific error message that is not understood, that could be included as a question title.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are on this line:

```
char cur = Character.toUpperCase(char);
```

That line should be:

```
cur = Character.toUpperCase(cur);
```

You have atleast two problems. The variable cur was being defined twice. You only need to specify the type 'char' once. Any other times and you would be redefining the variable. The other problem is the parameter 'char' you passed is not what you wanted to do. You want to pass your character into that function aka the variable you named 'cur'.

To be a bit more nitpicky, as clearly you are very new to atleast this programming language, simple modifications can be done to make the code a fair bit better.

```
// No need to have a separate variable for str.length() as it is only used once.
for(int i = 0;i < str.length();i++)
{

    // This really can be done on one line like this or as below.
    //char uppercaseCharacter = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i));

    char currentCharacter = str.charAt(i);

    char uppercaseCharacter = Character.toUpperCase(currentCharacter);

}
```

You, however, have a larger problem in that this code will not accomplish what you want it to do. At least in the current state. If you want to make the input string uppercase you need to modify it. In this case, you are simply copying the characters rather than modifying the original string. That question can be easily answered through a simple google search and is out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: Questions such as this (i.e., "why isn't my code working" without any specific problem or attempt to investigate) are off-topic and should not be answered.